# Cloudfront bucket - Media consumption using Query String parameter

Tags: amazon-s3, query-string, media, amazon-cloudfront, bucket

i would like to ask your help, since i read the Amazon guide talking about using Query String Parameters in the Urls to request content stored in buckets, and it was not clear to me.

So, i am planning to use a bucket to store Media content, and use Query String parameter for different versions of a media file. So, if i have an image, i can create the *original* version, the *small* version, the *large* version, and so on. Then, i can request the different versions on my website, based on my need.

But i did not understand how this is all managed. So, all the versions of the file, do they have the same file name? And using Powershell script to upload the files to the bucket, how do i specify the version that i am uploading?

Thank you.

Comment: I believe you're thinking of a different type of "version" than what the service documentation is referring to... but to be sure I'm understanding your question correctly, please provide a link to the documentation you're referring to.

Comment: Hi @Michael-sqlbot , here goes the [source](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/QueryStringParameters.html)